# Let $f:[a,b]\to L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be continuous, and consider $f:\mathbb{R}^d\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Then why is $f$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I wish to show that $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d\times[a,b]$ is measurable. Now, if we set $f_t = f(t):\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}$, then my idea is to somehow, for some $\varepsilon>0$ and $t_0\in[a,b]$, find a $\delta$ such that $|t-t_0|<\delta$ implies that $f_{t_0}^{-1}((\alpha+\varepsilon,\infty))\subseteq f_t^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))\subseteq f_{t_0}^{-1}((\alpha-\varepsilon,\infty))$ and use this to construct $f^{-1}((\alpha,\infty))$ by sandwiching, but I'm not even sure if this is true, and unfortunately, my measure theory is pretty rusty.

Comment: Just to clarify notation: for each $t \in [a,b]$ you have $f(t) \in L^1(\mathbb R^d)$, and you are defining $f(x,t) = f(t)(x)$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:[a,b]\to L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ be continuous, and consider $f:\mathbb{R}^d\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ may be non-measurable as the following example shows.

Consider a well-ordering defined in $[0,1]$. It defines a bijection $\varphi: [0, 1] \to \omega_1 $, where $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal.

For every $t\in [0,1]$, define $f(t)= \chi_{\{x\: : \: x\in [0,1] \textrm{ and } \varphi(x) < \varphi(t)\}}$.

Since, for every $t\in [0,1]$,  the set $\{x\: : \: x\in [0,1] \textrm{ and } \varphi(x) < \varphi(t)\}$ is countable, we have that $f(t)$ is null a.e., so $f(t) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

However, $f:\mathbb{R}\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$, is defined by $f(t,x)= 1$ iff $t\in [0,1]$ and $\varphi(x) < \varphi(t)$. Such function is not measurable. In fact, $f$ is the indicator function of a Sierpinski (non-measurable) set:
$$ \{(t,x)\in [0,1] \times[0,1] : \varphi(x) < \varphi(t) \} $$